# The application has stopped unexpectedly and all im trying to do is activate a button and go into another screen

Tags: java, android

I am doing a simple test to see if i can make an android game. All im tryihg to do is when the user clicks on my start button it goes into the game screen that for now says "Game screen" however when i click on the button it says the application has stopped Unexpected error has occured and i am forced to shut down.

I am new to eclipse and android but i am not new to java and my code has no errors

So if someone can help me fix this problem i would very much appreciate it

Here is my main:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonClickMethod();
    }

    private void buttonClickMethod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startB);
        start.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v){

                    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), GameView.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i,0);
                }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

here is my gameView code:

```
package com.example.coloroblind;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GameView extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
    }

}
```

thanks for your input

Comment: where is the code??? :)

Comment: Please show the code *and* the logcat output, i.e. the stack trace where your app crashes.

Comment: is R.id.startB declader inside  R.layout.activity_main ?

Comment: show us also your manifest

Comment: @StefanBe you're probably on the right track as you must declare all Activitys in the manifest in order to launch them, if you look at log cat it will even tell you that.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of your logcat?

Comment: If the problem is not declared activity in logcat should be written something like "did you declared yourActivity in manifest?"

Comment: yes, to help us figure out your problem post your stack trace and manifest file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can pretty much guess your problem lies in the Android Manifest. Have you declared your GameView Activity there? It should be  `<activity android:name=".GameView" />` and here is some sample code where to put it.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GameView" />
</application>
```

Comment: You sir no how to explain things that normal people can understand thank you soo much

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Simon, whenever you make a new Intent , you have to entry it in your manifest file.
All your intents should be present over here.